# Best practices synchronizing CursorLoader test cases

Tags: android, junit, android-contentprovider, android-testing, android-cursorloader

I've just switched to using CursorLoaders and I'm having trouble writing tests that utilize them.  Since using the CursorLoader methodology takes the querying off of the main thread `getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync()` is returning before the adapter is being updated (or at least this is my theory).  I'm trying to avoid this is all my tests

```
public void testUpdateList() throws InvalidRecord, InterruptedException {
    ListView listView = frag.getListView();
    // Verify list is empty
    assertEquals(0, listView.getCount());

    // Add transaction directly into database
    transTable.addOccurrences(resolver, TestUtils.createMockTrans());

    //Don't want to do this but it works.   
    synchronized (this) {
        wait(500);
        assertEquals(1, listView.getCount());
    }
}
```

So my question is, is there a better way to test this functionality within the Android testing framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I settled on was using the `waitForCondition` method within Robotium.  Here is an example.

```
...
 // Waits for 500 milliseconds for the condition to be meet.  
 // If it isn't meet within this time limit the result is false.
 boolean isSatisfied =  solo.waitForCondition( new Condition() {
    public boolean isSatisfied() {
      return listView.getCount() == 1;
    }, 500);

  //Then I check if the condition has been meet.
  assertTrue(isSatisfied);
...
```